# Нужно сжимать фото при выдаче пользователю PHP, Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, изображения, get

Видел как get параметрами сжимают картинки на сайте. например `http://site.com/img.jpg?w=100&h=150&c=7` как это реализовать. Суть в том что хочу загружать на сайт фотки в хорошем разрешении, а потом на клиенте сжимать, делать качество чуть хуже, менять размер, как это реализовать?

Comment: Есть вариант `Yii2 glide`.. да он их режет, все круто, но обработка на серваке слишком долгая... была страница 1.4, грузится за 180-300DOM, после glide стала 1.2 и грузится 360DOM+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может быть пригодится

```
public function optimize($image)
{
    $size = 512;

    $ext = pathinfo($image);

    if (!array_key_exists('extension',$ext)){
        throw new Exception('Отсутствует разширение файла!');
    }
    if (!array_key_exists('filename',$ext)){
        throw new Exception('Отсутствует имя файла!');
    }
    $extension = $ext['extension'];

    if($extension == ""){
        throw new Exception('Отсутствует разширение файла!');
    }

    $im = new Imagick($image);

    $height = $im->getImageHeight();
    $width = $im->getImageWidth();

    if($height < $size && $width < $size){
        $im->adaptiveResizeImage($width,$height);
    }

    if($height > $size && $width > $size && $height == $width){
        $im->adaptiveResizeImage($size,$size);
    }

    if($height > $width && $height > $size){
        $im->adaptiveResizeImage(0,$size);
    }

    if($width > $height && $width > $size){
        $im->adaptiveResizeImage($size,0);
    }

    // Optimize the image layers
    $im->optimizeImageLayers();

    // Compression and quality
    $im->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);

    $im->setImageCompressionQuality(55);

    // Write the image back
    $im->writeImages($image, true);

}
```

Comment: Любой ответ, который направляет спрашивающего в нужное русло, является ценным. Возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше. Чтобы улучшить данный ответ, можно добавит информацию о библиотеке, которая используетс в решении, для чего она предназначена, способы подключения, ссылку на документацию.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что простейший вариант — поставить imagemagick и жать с помощью его утилит convert или mogrify через system()

Захочется интегрироваться поплотнее — есть [пыховый модуль](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.imagick.php).